# Use NumPy to generate a kneighbors_graph like scikit-learn?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to brush up on my understanding of some basic ML method. Can someone explain what is going on under the hood with `kneighbors_graph`? I would like to replicate this output with only NumPy.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import kneighbors_graph

X = [[0, 1], [3, 4], [7, 8]]
A = kneighbors_graph(X, 2, mode='distance', include_self=True)
A.toarray()
```

Output:

```
array([[0.        , 4.24264069, 0.        ],
       [4.24264069, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 5.65685425, 0.        ]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resulting matrix represents the distance-weighted graph of *n* = 2 neighbours for each point in `X`, where you are including a point as its own neighbour (with a distance of zero). Note that distances to non-neighbours are also zero, so you might want to check the connectivity graph to know if you're looking at a zero-distance neighbour or a non-neighbour.

Let's start with the first row, representing the first point, `[0, 1]`. Here's what the numbers in that row mean:

- The first `0` is the distance to the nearest point, which is itself (because you specified `include_self=True`). If you specified `mode='connectivity'` this would be a 1, because it's a neighbour.
- The second element, `4.24`, is the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) (aka L2 norm) to the next point in `X`, which is `[3, 4]`. You get this distance because `metric='minkowski', p=2` are defaults; if you want a different distance metric, you can have it. Again, if you specified `mode='connectivity'` this would also be a 1, because it's a neighbour.
- The third element, another `0`, is not really a distance; it's telling you that the third point, `[7, 8]`, is **not** a neighbour when `n_neighbors` is 2. If you specified `mode='connectivity'` this would be a 0, because it's not a neighbour.

You can compute the distances between all pairs of points in an array with [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(X, X)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html). There's also [`scipy.spatial.KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) for neighbour lookup. If you really want to go pure NumPy, check out the `linalg` module.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to explain how the second row is calculated? How does the second row yield 4.24264069, 0, 0?

Comment: It's the same idea as the first row, but for the second point. The 4.24 is the distance from the second point to the first. The first 0 is the distance from the second point to itself (because `self=True`). And the second 0 is there because the third point is not an `n=2` neighbour, which you can tell from the `mode='connectivity'` matrix.